# How to create layout capture in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Ultimate) for Android developing. And I remember that couple of version ago I could make capture of layout from attached device.
But now I can't find how to do it.
Layout Captures tool window present but how to make captures have no idea :(

For Android Studio it's easy to do - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a project with IntelliJ and I found this :

[image]

So then you can choose the one that is running in your device as follows

[image]

Is that what you were looking for?